# how to convert DataFrame[pvalue: double] into real values

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am selecting a value from a dataframe using a `where` condition:

```
df.select(df["id"]).where((df["amt"]==10) & (df["type"]==19))
```

it gives below value instead of real value:

```
DataFrame[pvalue: double]
```

If I use:

```
df.select(df["id"]).where((df["amt"]==10) & (df["type"]==19)).show()
```

it gives real values.

How to convert it to real number/value?

Comment: but...... It seems like you found a way to display the real values. Am I missing something?

Comment: The above code is being used in a function. The return (result is a float value). but when I multiple it with a number it throws error. reason being the return type is  a dataframe and not a single value ..What function/code should I use so that the result it returned as a value and not a dataframe